# ListView notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-listview

I have `ListView` s that keeps messeages of comments. First is message others are comments.
If user send comments It should appear behind of message.It is second row in `listview`.
When user make a comment I use `notifyDataSetChanged()`.Inserted  comments appear in `listview` but in the last row. I have sorting algorithm that keeps `ArrayList` what i want in sorting..
Although `ArrayList` sorted, Inserted comment appear in last row. It should not be.

Why `notifyDataSetChanged()` don't  keep `Listview` according to `ArrayList`.It  just update it new element to last row

Answer (score 0):

notifyDataSetChanged() will notify data set change to listview, i think you need to modify arraylist and then call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: that is what i do. It is inserted the last row

Comment: In this case reinitialize list with sorted array using adapter.